# iCloud NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation

Tags: core-data, ios7, icloud, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am facing issue like **NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.**

In my app, when app is launch and contact sync process in background using separate manageObjectContext and successfully contacts sync in background.

I am already setup for iCloud configuration.

I have one option in my app with **iCloud ON/OFF in setting** so whenever iCloud is ON and remove app from background in device and start again so at that time **app is crashed due to persistentStore while save manageObjectContext in core data.**

Please give me suggestion or any idea.

Thanks for advance in help.

**Please see my below code for iCloud**

**PFCoreDataController.h**

```
@interface PFCoreDataController : NSObject
{
    NSManagedObjectModel            *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext          *managedObjectContext;      
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator    *persistentStoreCoordinator;

}

@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly)NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property(nonatomic, retain, readonly)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property(nonatomic, readonly)NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *settingsArray;
@property(nonatomic, readwrite)int iCloudValue;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextBack;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContextBackTEST;
@property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableDictionary *keycontactDict;

+ (PFCoreDataController *)sharedCoreDataController;

PFCoreDataController.m

+ (PFCoreDataController *)sharedCoreDataController
{
    if(coreDataController == nil)
    {
        coreDataController = [[PFCoreDataController alloc]init];

    }
    return coreDataController;
}

// For iCloud use below section
- (NSManagedObjectContext *) managedObjectContext
{
    if (managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];


    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
        self.keycontactDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        BOOL isiCloudValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:iCLOUD_VALUE];
        if (isiCloudValue)
        {
            DLog(@"iCloud enabled");
            float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
            DLog(@"into Version %f",ver);

            if (ver >= 5.0)
            {
                NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];

                [moc performBlockAndWait:^{
                    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
                    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(mergeChangesFrom_iCloud:) name:NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification object:coordinator];
                }];
                managedObjectContext = moc;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
            [managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];

            self.managedObjectContextBack = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
            [self.managedObjectContextBack setUndoManager:nil];
            [self.managedObjectContextBack setParentContext:managedObjectContext];

            self.managedObjectContextBackTEST = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
            [self.managedObjectContextBackTEST setUndoManager:nil];
            [self.managedObjectContextBackTEST setParentContext:managedObjectContext];

//            self.managedObjectContextUI = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
//            [self.managedObjectContextUI setUndoManager:nil];
//            [self.managedObjectContextUI setParentContext:managedObjectContext];
//            
//            self.managedObjectContextBack = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSConfinementConcurrencyType];
//            [self.managedObjectContextBack setUndoManager:nil];
//            [self.managedObjectContextBack setParentContext:managedObjectContext];

        }
    }

    return managedObjectContext;
}
// For iCloud use below section
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{  
    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    BOOL isiCloudValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:iCLOUD_VALUE];
    if (isiCloudValue)
    {
        DLog(@"iCloud enabled");
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PurpleFolder" withExtension:@"momd"];
        managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    }
    else{
        managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];
    }
    return managedObjectModel;

}
// For iCloud use below section

- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{

    if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:SQLITE_FILE_NAME]];

    BOOL isiCloudValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:iCLOUD_VALUE];

    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

    if (isiCloudValue)
    {
        DLog(@"iCloud enabled");
        NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

        float ver = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

        if (ver >= 5.0)
        {

            DLog(@"into Version %f",ver);


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

                // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you MUST change this variable:
                NSString *iCloudEnabledAppID = @"NB8QU2BXAM.com.siliconithub.icloudtest";

                // ** Note: if you adapt this code for your own use, you should change this variable:
                NSString *dataFileName = @"iCloud.sqlite";

                // ** Note: For basic usage you shouldn't need to change anything else

                NSString *iCloudDataDirectoryName = @"Data.nosync";
                NSString *iCloudLogsDirectoryName = @"Logs";
                NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                NSURL *urlFromAppDocDirectory =  [NSURL URLWithString:[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
                //            NSURL *localStore = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

                NSURL *localStore = [urlFromAppDocDirectory URLByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
                NSURL *iCloud = [fileManager URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];

                if (iCloud) {

                    DLog(@"iCloud is working");

                    NSURL *iCloudLogsPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudLogsDirectoryName]];

                    DLog(@"iCloudEnabledAppID = %@",iCloudEnabledAppID);
                    DLog(@"dataFileName = %@", dataFileName);
                    DLog(@"iCloudDataDirectoryName = %@", iCloudDataDirectoryName);
                    DLog(@"iCloudLogsDirectoryName = %@", iCloudLogsDirectoryName);
                    DLog(@"iCloud = %@", iCloud);
                    DLog(@"iCloudLogsPath = %@", iCloudLogsPath);

                    if([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]] == NO) {
                        NSError *fileSystemError;
                        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[[iCloud path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                               withIntermediateDirectories:YES
                                                attributes:nil
                                                     error:&fileSystemError];
                        if(fileSystemError != nil) {
                            DLog(@"Error creating database directory %@", fileSystemError);
                        }
                    }

                    NSString *iCloudData = [[[iCloud path]
                                             stringByAppendingPathComponent:iCloudDataDirectoryName]
                                            stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];

                    DLog(@"iCloudData = %@", iCloudData);

                    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
                    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];
                    [options setObject:iCloudEnabledAppID            forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey];
                    [options setObject:iCloudLogsPath                forKey:NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey];

                    [psc lock];

                    [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                      configuration:nil
                                                URL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:iCloudData]
                                            options:options
                                              error:nil];

                    [psc unlock];
                }
                else {
                    DLog(@"iCloud is NOT working - using a local store");

                    NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption];
                    [options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption];

                    [psc lock];

                    [psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                      configuration:nil
                                                URL:localStore
                                            options:options
                                              error:nil];
                    [psc unlock];

                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    DLog(@"into dispatech");
                    NSUserDefaults *stdef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    if ([stdef integerForKey:@"iPhoneQuoteiCloudAutoPost"] == 1)
                    {
                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SomethingChanged" object:self userInfo:nil];
                    }

                });
            });

        }

        else
        {
            NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption,
                                     nil];

            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
            {
                DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                abort();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSError *error = nil;
        NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

        if (![self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error])
        {
            DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }

    return self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

// Returns the path to the application's documents directory.
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory 
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}


- (BOOL)addDefalultValuesToSettings
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    NSError *error; 
    Settings *defaultSettings = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_SETTINGS inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    defaultSettings.setCalendar=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    defaultSettings.addActionsToNotes=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    defaultSettings.addTimeStampToNote=[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];

    **if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error])** 
    {
        DLog(@"Failed to save addDefalultValuesToSettings in dB: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        success = NO;
    }

    return success; 
}
```

Comment: Not sure, but you've got a couple of calls to `addPersistentStoreWithType:` in there where you're not checking the return value or providing an error parameter. That seems like a good place to start looking.

Comment: @TomHarrington I have put condition for iCloud integration with core data and plz suggest me how can I use proper use of persistentStore with iCloud?

Comment: @TomHarrington Plz see my updated code and add addDefalultValuesToSettings method and in that method if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) app is crashed at this line.

Comment: You're still not making any attempt to check that your calls to `addPersistentStoreWithType:` succeeded. If you don't have any persistent stores, one or more of them probably failed. You're not even checking to see if things are working properly, and that's the first thing you need to change.